# NFC_manager flutter package reading NFC not work in android

Tags: android, nfc, flutter-packages

I've followed 'NFC_manager' example, https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager/example

Successfully build in my android phone and check NFC instance avaiable when I turn on NFC mode.

Howerver, clicking the 'Tag Read' button, it should be started to scan NFC tags.

[photo-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgSAR.jpg)

But 'NFC_manager' cannot catch any tag.

After some time past, below error message appear in the text box as below photo.

[photo-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2jw.jpg)

Is there anything else I missed?

Comment: What type of Tag (Make and Model) are you using? It possibly looks like you are using a proprietary Mifare Classic? While it looks like your phone supports this type of Tag not all will. Also how are you bringing the Tag in to range? Normally you would press the Read button and then bring the Tag within range of the phone. But doing it the other way around can work but again on some hardware it does not.

Comment: 1. What type of Tag (Make and Model) are you using? -> Is it important formatting type of Tag? I don't know that, I just thought NFC-tag same with QR-code. 2. Normally you would press the Read button and then bring the Tag within range of the phone. -> Yes, specifically, I've tested with 2 type hardware, one is NFC-tag attached sensor device maybe includes information about sensor, another is other android phone emulating NFC-tag. 3. Mifare Classic -> Inspecting about NFC, I could see the word 'Mifare Classic' but I ignored it because I thought this is not related to my test, directly.

Comment: There are many different types of Tag hardware and Mifare Classic is a non standard type and not supported well on some phones. But I would say that the text you are getting in the text box is what you should be expecting for a Mifare Classic from the line `result.value = tag.data;` so the read code is working but I don't know why is it so delayed.